# Required CommonMultipartFile parameter 'testFile' is not present in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

when I upload a file to springmvc, getting a error message "Required CommonsMultipartFile parameter 'textFile' is not present", I don't know why I can meet it, that's my code.

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
<input type="file" id="file" name="textFile" />
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="上传" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
    var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/giraffe/upload1",
        type:"post",
        data:form,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data){
            alert("success！");
        }
    });
}
```

That's my controller and configuration.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000"/>
</bean>

@RequestMapping(path = "/upload1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object updloadImage(@RequestParam("textFile") CommonsMultipartFile file){
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to add a good problem description. It also might help to add more tags to the question. Otherwise you won't get any answers. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your RequestParam to

```
@RequestParam MultipartFile textFile
```

This is of type "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile"

Also important is that you expose the commons library to your server. So you must add your commons-fileupload-x.x.x.jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

And your controller must add the path

```
@RequestMapping(value="/giraffe")
```

because your AJAX-Request points to /giraffe/upload1

To check what and if anything is presented to the controller you can add

```
@RequestParam (required=false) ...
```

If you have an jsp-File for the page and no plain html then you can use the jstl. This can help you avoid problems with the correct url in your AJAX-request. Like this

```
url: "<c:url value='/giraffe/upload1' />",
```